# Maven release:prepare fails to commit tag

Tags: git, maven-release-plugin

Attempting to perform a release on a maven project, which has successfully released before.

When I perform `mvn release:prepare` I am prompted for the release tags and the new snapshot tags and the project builds.

But when it attempts to push to the remote, I get

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0:prepare (default-cli) on project NeuralAnalysis: Unable to tag SCM
    [ERROR] Provider message:
    [ERROR] The git-push command failed.
    [ERROR] Command output:
    [ERROR] To ssh://gitosis@10.41.129.2/NeuralAnalysis.git
    [ERROR] ! [rejected]        NeuralAnalysis-1.5.6 -> NeuralAnalysis-1.5.6 (non-fast-forward)
    [ERROR] error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://gitosis@10.41.129.2/NeuralAnalysis.git'
    [ERROR] To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected`

And indeed, attempting to perform  `git push ssh://gitosis@10.41.129.2/NeuralAnalysis.git NeuralAnalysis-1.5.6` manually, also exits with the same complaint.

Performing `git pull` says 'Already up-to-date'. `git branch` shows I am on the 'master'. `git push origin` gives 'Everything up-to-date'.

Looking at the repository using Tower shows that 'master', 'origin/master' and 'NeuralAnalysis-1.5.6' are all the same and on the last commit. The working directory contains release.properties and pom.xml.releaseBackup files.

It looks to me like everything is fine with the repository overall.

Comment: Do you have (locally or on the remote) a *branch* named `NeuralAnalysis-1.5.6` like the tag you are trying to push? Can you edit your question with the output of a `git push --verbose ssh://gitosis@10.41.129.2/NeuralAnalysis.git NeuralAnalysis-1.5.6`?

Answer (score 14):

Turns out it was a remote tag with the same name, as suggested by VonC in the comment. This was likely created by some previously aborted release.

Although I found the remote tag by manually inspecting the refs/tags directory on the remote repository,  `git ls-remote --tags` will show them as well and the `git push --verbose` will also show more about the problem in general.

To fix this, first retrieve the remote tags with `git fetch --tags`.

One way to perform the next step is then to simply bypass that release tag by updating the pom.xml to have a higher -SNAPSHOT version (including any references in the same project by other modules to that snapshot), check these in, and do `mvn release:clean; mvn release:prepare` over again.